# Cannot resolve symbol protobuf in android application

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

I am trying to send `protobuf` data from cpp side to java side (Android Application).

I have generated `.java` file using `protoc --java_out` option and included that file in my android project.

How do I link `protobuf` library to my android application ?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `Gradle` to manage your project dependencies, there is a JAR available in JCenter.

Add the following to your `build.gradle` dependencies

```
compile "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1"
```